# Bring a Chrome custom dev tools panel into focus

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a custom panel extension with a context menu that allows a user right click an element on the web page, to see the definition of the element. The definition is shown in the panel but the panel doesn't receive focus and the user must click dev tools first.

Given a Chrome custom panel extension created like this

```
devtools.js
chrome.devtools.panels.create(..., function (panel) {
    const thisTabId = chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.tabId;

    chrome.windows.update(thisTabId, {focused:true}); 
    //Tells me "Uncaught (in promise) Error: No window with id: 365875404."

    panel.show()  //This is a valid function (that's not in the docs) and doesn't do anything.

})
```

Is there a programmatic way for devtools.js to bring an open panel into focus? The same way a js breakpoint brings the sources panel into focus, even when it's behind another application.